# Using `RenderEffect` with a `Bitmap` instead of `ImageView`

Tags: android, kotlin, graphics

I want to blur a `Bitmap` object in Android, currently I have the following code which blurs an `ImageView`:

```
private fun blurImageView(radius: Float) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 31) {
        binding.activityMainImageView.setRenderEffect(
            RenderEffect.createBlurEffect(radius, radius, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP)
        )
    }
}
```

I want to get the underlying `Bitmap` object, so I tried to achieve that by doing the following:

```
binding.activityMainImageView.drawToBitmap()
```

But it doesn't seem to be working.

So how would I go around simply blurring a `Bitmap` object, is this possible with `RenderScript` at all? If not, what are my options to create a blur effect on a `Bitmap` object and get the underlying `Bitmap` object?

**The developer documentation has given no info on how you could go around doing this.**

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bitmap blur effect in Android using RenderScript API!

The code maybe like this:

```
public Bitmap blur(Bitmap image) {
if (null == image){
    return null;
}

Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image);
final RenderScript renderScript = RenderScript.create(this);
Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, image);
Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, outputBitmap);

//Intrinsic Gausian blur filter
ScriptIntrinsicBlur theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(renderScript, Element.U8_4(renderScript));
theIntrinsic.setRadius(25); //should be 0-25
theIntrinsic.setInput(tmpIn);
theIntrinsic.forEach(tmpOut);
tmpOut.copyTo(outputBitmap);
return outputBitmap;
}
```

Then use:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.test_pic);
Bitmap blurredBitmap = blur(bitmap);
```

Hope this can help you!

Comment: Thank you very much for your well though out answer, since my karma is going to expire I think you deserve it. The only issue I have is that RenderScript is deprecated and will stop functioning in the future altogether (according to Google), which is unfortunate and why I want a RenderEffect solution. If you can help find a RenderEffect solution that would be great (or any other non-deprecated way to achieve what I want). This decision from Google is frustrating :(

Comment: @thebluepandabear I got you! I want to know what do you want to get the underlying bitmap for? Because according to the official document,  When you're blurring the ImageView, you don't have to get the bitmap data, process the image, create a new Bitmap, and set it back to the ImageView. RenderEffect leverages existing rendering pipelines, minimizing additional computation. If you just want a blur effect for ImageView, just do this is fine !

Comment: I want to get the Bitmap because I am creating a pixel art editor and I need individual Bitmap data. Using your code gives me **deprecation warnings** which isn't good, but I appreciate your helping me in finding a solution. I have sent an issue to Google in regards to this, please upvote it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/249021405

Comment: Deprecation warnings are a sign that the class/method/property will get deleted in the future and thus you should minimize the amount of times you used deprecated code so you don't mess things up when you update your libraries and your code won't be able to compile.